# How to limit char length

Tags: c++

I know people will immediately look at the title and just say: "Use String" or "Char can only be length of 1" but there are problems with those.

For the first, due to later on in the code using a switch statement my variable must stay as a char so that it does not cause any errors, and for the second answer during testing I found out that even if I entered a multi-length input it would just run each character into the switch statement separately which I do not want to happen. Any help is welcomed, oh and here's the code:

```
char input;
do {
    cout << "Please enter a number from 1 to 4.";
    cin >> input;
    if (sizeof(input)!=1) {
        cout << "Please just enter a number";
    }
    else {

        switch (input) {

        case '1': {
            cout << "One";
            break;
        }

        case '2': {
            cout << "Two";
            break;
        }

        case '3': {
            cout << "Three";
            break;
        }

        case '4': {
            cout << "Four";
            break;
        }

        default:

            cout << "Enter only a number from 1-4!";

        }

    }
    
} while ((input) != '4');
```

Note that I have at least attempted to use strlen and the size functions but to no avail.

Comment: `char` cannot store more than one character. It cannot have greater length. You can solve your problem in different ways, depending if you want to ignore the rest of the line that user entered or show them error if they enter more than one character in the line.

Comment: `sizeof(input)` is constant expression and is always equal to `1`. `sizeof` gives value which is always know during compile time (run time can't impact result).

Comment: both your "cannot because..." reasons are not really reasons. For the first: `x[0]` is the first character in a string, you can switch on that. For the second: You can use `std::cin.ignore()` to ignore input that is left in the stream after reading one `char`

Comment: Please explain desired behavior. Current code and description are not clear and your solution is simply invalid and can't be fixed (without knowledge what it suppose to do).

Comment: Well largest prime, your second point was actually the answer I needed. Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with `int input; std::cin >> input;` (`case 1:`)?

Comment: @Jarod42 That won't quite work if the user types, say, `x` - something that doesn't at all look like a number.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: there is still error handling: `if (!std::cin) {std::cin.ignore(..); ..}`. and AFAIR, `input` will be set to 0 in that case, so not in range 1-4 ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Well, use `string`, because `char` can only be length of 1.

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
if (input.size() != 1) {
  std::cout << "Wrong input";
} else {
  switch (input.front()) {
  case '1': 
  // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What library is .first from? I have the namespace and string library already included but it won't show up for me.

Comment: Typo; I meant `front`.